# Laravel: Missing 1 argument for App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::show()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

When I click "Profile" in home.blade.php I am having an error, "Missing 1 argument for App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::show()" how to solve this error?

home.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="sidebar col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Navigation</div>
                  @if (Auth::user()->type === "Admin")
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="{{ URL::to('users') }}">Users</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="{{ URL::to('adlogs') }}">Logs</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 @elseif (Auth::user()->type === "Employee")
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="{{ URL::to('profile') }}">Profile</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="{{ URL::to('logs') }}"> Logs</a></li>
                    </ul>
                @else

                @endif
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    You are logged in!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::resource('/profile', 'ProfileController@show');
```

HomeController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        return view('home');
    }

}
```

ProfileController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
class ProfileController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {

    }


    public function create()
    {
        //
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }


    public function show($id)
    {
        $users = User::find($id);

        return view('profile.index',compact('users'));


    }


    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

and this is index.blade.php of Profile folder. This is where should be the output.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <td>User ID</td>
                        <td>First Name</td>
                        <td>Last Name</td>
                        <td>Email</td>
                        <td>Job Title</td>
                        <td>Contact No</td>
                        <td>ABN Number</td>
                        <td>Status</td>
                        <td>Type</td>
                        <td>Action</td>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>                                     
                        @foreach($users as $value)  
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $value->id }}</td>                           
                                <td>{{ $value->first_name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $value->last_name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $value->email }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $value->job_title }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $value->contact_no }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $value->abn_number }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $value->status }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $value->type }}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="{{ URL::to('users/' . $value->id . '/edit') }}">
                                        Edit
                                    </a>                                                    
                                    <a href="{{ URL::to('users/' . $value->id . '/destroy') }}">
                                        Delete
                                    </a>
                                </td>   
                            </tr>                   
                         @endforeach                                         
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>



        </div>
    </div>
 @endsection
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Why laravel 5.3? The current version is 5.5

Comment: this is what the client wants

Comment: how to solve this problem man?

Comment: 5.3 was released on 23 Aug 2016, long time ago

Comment: Define individual routes for every method instead of using route resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using

```
Route::resource...
```

you can't specify a function. Just use:

```
Route::resource('/profile', 'ProfileController');
```

**EDIT:**

`Route::resource` creates 6 routes for you. See my image below.

As your route needs a parameter (the `$id`) you need to pass it a parameter. Maybe it's easier to use named routes also. So instead of

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('profile') }}">Profile</a>
```

you would write

```
<a href="{{ route('profile.show', Auth::user()->id) }}">Profile</a>
```

You can see all available routes with the command

```
php artisan route:list
```

The output should look like this:
[image: artisan route:list output]

Comment: problem still not solved. i remove the @show and it has no output. and when i use "get" instead of "resource" i still get the same error, "Missing 1 argument"

Comment: if use get u need to pass id value wich u use show($id) route be like Route::get('/profile/{id}', 'ProfileController@show');

Comment: i use your method and i get another error: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Comment: NotFoundHttpException means that there is no route defined. Have you defined `Route::resource('/profile', 'ProfileController');` in your routes/web.php?

Comment: @PKeidel profile.show is not visible in name column while using route list

Comment: are the routes listet correctly when checking with `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: it has profile/{id} in the URI column and App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@show in Action column but it has no name

Comment: I tested it in my current project and it works. Laravel 5.3 supports that https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers but you should consider updating laravel to the latest version. Maybe you could use the link to check all your files

Comment: From your image, I can see that this is not from `Route::resource`. Remove your `Route::get('profile', ...)` and use just the `Route::resource('/profile', 'ProfileController')`

Answer (score 3):

This situation will have much solution.

> Solution number one

You can change the route look like this

```
Route::resource('/profile/{id}', 'ProfileController@show');
```

> Solution number two

Used the same route and you can change your controller looks like this

```
public function show()
{
    $id = Auth::id();
    $users = User::find($id);

    return view('profile.index',compact('users'));

}
```

i hope this anwers can help your problems

Comment: i am having an error: Route pattern "/profile/{id}/{{id}}" cannot reference variable name "id" more than once.

Comment: this doesn't work with Route::resource because with resource you cannot use route placeholders

Comment: You can try to used like this, Route::resource('user', 'AdminUserController', ['parameters' => [
    'id' => 'admin_id'
]]);

Comment: Your resource route is wrong and you are waisting a lot of resources by your way of fetching the authenticated user (hint: `Auth::user()` is a thing)

Comment: No, used $id = Auth::id(); is for get the currently authenticated user's ID. And we don't need to send that again from get url

Comment: @PKeidel i change the route. i used get instead of resource

Answer (score 0):

[here is the route list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFi3s.png)

profile{id} has no name in it

Answer (score 0):

in route

```
Route::resource('/profile', 'ProfileController');
```

in view

```
     <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="{{ URL::to('profile/'.Auth::user()->id)}}">Profile</a></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="{{ URL::to('logs') }}"> Logs</a</li>
    </ul>
```

eg. $id may be 1, then it will be routed to the show method in
                ProfileController.php

```
             public function show($id){
                    $users = User::find($id);
                    return view('profile.index',compact('users'));
                }
```

Comment: there is an error:  Undefined variable: id (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\DTR\resources\views\home.blade.php)

Comment: you must pass $id to the view, actually i meant by profile id, 
public function index() {
        $id = Auth::user()->id;
        return view('home', compact('id'));
    }

or use can use directly in view, like
  <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="{{ URL::to('profile/'.Auth::user()->id)}}">Profile</a></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><a href="{{ URL::to('logs') }}"> Logs</a</li>
    </ul>